# cannot read property myProperty of undefined with angular library

Tags: angular

I am using ngx-audio-player, a library with a simple clean playlist functionality that works fine if I hardcode the songs, but I need to load them dynamically. So I create an array in the same format as the hardcoded version, which takes type: "Track[]", but it returns the titular error. I can't figure out why, because the array I'm passing in should be literally exactly the same as if it was hardcoded.
SO hardcoded into the class exporter it works:

```
msaapPlaylist: Track[] = [ {
    title: 'Audio One Title',
    link: 'assets/music/Ghost Story.mp3'
  }];
```

but if I initialize it like

```
  msaapPlaylist: Track[] = [ ];
```

then build msaapPlaylist from my data during my playlist creation function (there are criteria to sort and create playlists):

```
  this.msaapPlaylist.push({title: song.title, link: song.link});
```

The console throws the above error and stops loading the page.
If I disable the html that builds the player and consolelog the constructed playlist, I can see that it builds it just fine. But I don't even seem to get there if I don't have the array pre loaded like the first example.  nor does it load afterwards, supposing I put a dummy song in there and then push after it. the array builds, but the player does not load any more songs.
here is my html:

```
<div class="container">
  <mat-advanced-audio-player [playlist]="msaapPlaylist" [displayTitle]="msaapDisplayTitle"
  [displayPlaylist]="msaapDisplayPlayList" [pageSizeOptions]="msaapPageSizeOptions"
      [displayVolumeControls]="msaapDisplayVolumeControls" [expanded]="true"></mat-advanced-audio-player>
</div>
```

Comment: can u explain more. I am not able to understand the exact issue , and please add more code

Comment: made edits, unless you want to see more code. be a bit hard to keep it concise as other things are happening, but I could try

Comment: same problem here, did you find the fix? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On HTML tag try to add *ngIf="msaapPlaylist.length > 0".